# how to copy a string field data to integer field in solr without reindex?

Tags: solr, lucene

how to copy a string field data to integer field in solr without reindex because data volume is very high ?
I have a field name brvc which is string , I like to use this for sorting in solr but due to field type string this is not working properly .

I like to make a new field like 

this but how to copy all data from brvc to brvc_new . data volume is very high .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Atomic Updates](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) to update documents, including adding the new field to the document.

However, the only way to update a document is to remove and reindex it.  Functions that update documents in Lucene are just a convenient wrapper on the process of removing specified documents followed by adding new ones.  If you only have some portion of the index that needs to be modified, then running updates may make sense.  Keep in mind that all fields must be *stored* (or copyFields), otherwise their contents can not be retrieved from the existing index, and will be lost.

If you want to update every document with the new field, though, reindexing the whole thing is likely your best bet.